# Creating new excel workbook file returns invalid/corrupted error

Tags: vba, excel, file

I am trying to create a new excel workbook with VBA.  Unfortunately it keeps giving me this error message:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can create a new workbook.  The code below works perfectly for a CSV file.

I believe the line: `Open PathName & "\Test12345.xlsm" For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum` is causing the issue.

```
Sub WriteFile()

  Dim ColNum As Integer
  Dim Line As String
  Dim LineValues() As Variant
  Dim OutputFileNum As Integer
  Dim PathName As String
  Dim RowNum As Integer
  Dim SheetValues() As Variant

  PathName = "C:\Wa Guide\9 Projects\1 Bet365\Betting System Output\Z"
  OutputFileNum = FreeFile

  Open PathName & "\Test123.xls" For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum

  Print #OutputFileNum, "Field1" & "," & "Field2"

  SheetValues = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H9").Value
  ReDim LineValues(1 To 8)

  For RowNum = 1 To 9
    For ColNum = 1 To 8
      LineValues(ColNum) = SheetValues(RowNum, ColNum)
    Next
    Line = Join(LineValues, ",")
    Print #OutputFileNum, Line
  Next

  Close OutputFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using Test12345.xlsb or simply Test12345.xls since they both can store VBA code.

Comment: @KresimirL. Yeah I tried using those variations.  It tends to give same message.

Comment: This is never going to work. An excel file is a very complicated structure, not a simple text file. You can't use Open and write on anything except a simple text file. You need to use Workbooks.Add  and activeworkbook.saveas (filename) and go from there

Comment: you have to open it for `binary` access